# How to include a login form in the header part of the html page

Tags: php, html, ajax, codeigniter, authentication

I am trying to implement a log-in form in the header part of my html page.

Log-in form in the sense, i just want to show a pop-up text box , when a url is called.

**Example** : `when a user try to call "www.myserver.com/lodapages.html" i want the user to enter a password before the content of the page loads.`

if the password matches , then the user can see the page contents else no.

This is what happens when we generally tries to access mysql server.

So, Can anybody assist me to work on this. or is there any other way of simple implementation ? 
  I am using php codeigniter.

Comment: Actually i didnt get your requirement.Why are you include HTML instead of PHP?

Comment: Are you looking for Apache based, check this out http://www.seochat.com/c/a/search-engine-optimization-help/apache-basic-user-authentication-htpasswd-tutorial-for-seo/

Comment: @Jerin i have those values stored in database. So i need a html to input data and then validate the given password from database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't easily prevent a page to load with a popup like that.

Either you go and code a standard three steps authentication :

1. the user requests the page
2. if he is athenticated, he gets it, else he is redirected to a login page
3. if the authentication scucceds, then, he is redirected to the requested page

Or you simply use [htaccess protection](http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/password-protection/) (wich will actually popu-up an authentication dialog...) :

Answer (score 1):

```
on load call javascript prompt method and get password from user after that redirect user to next page.
```

Answer (score 1):

In codeigniter, maybe you can use a login.php view as the default view page, when a user try to call your pages, login.php will be displayed and the user is required to enter password.After the user enters the right password, you can use the controller login to redirect the page to lodapages.html.